# If a creature with an effect is destroyed by blocking do other attacking creatures lose the effect?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a [Rageblood Shaman](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rageblood%20shaman) that says:

> Other Minotaur creatures you control get +1/+1 and have trample.

If I attack with it and multiple other creatures any my opponent blocks it and destroys it do my other creatures still have +1/+1 and trample when their damage is dealt?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I might have found my own answer writing this ask but I'll post it so others can comment if I'm wrong and learn if I'm right:

Yes given rule [510.2](http://magic.wizards.com/en/gameinfo/gameplay/formats/comprehensiverules) which says:

> 510.2. Second, all combat damage that’s been assigned is dealt simultaneously. This turn-based action doesn’t use the stack. No player has the chance to cast spells or activate abilities between the time combat damage is assigned and the time it’s dealt. This is a change from previous rules.

If combat damage is done simultaneously then the damage is done to the Rageblood Shaman at the same time that the other creatures affected by the Shaman are dealing damage, thus it has not been destroyed yet and the effect still applies.

Comment: An exception is when your shaman is blocked by a creature with first strike for example

Comment: That's correct (though it's rule 510.2, you have a typo in your link text). In fact the combat damage is dealt first, and then only later, immediately prior to the action described in rule 510.3, do creatures actually die if they've received lethal damage. (see rules 116.5 and 704.3)

Comment: Also, this answer only works if the Shaman is killed _by_ the combat damage itself; if your opponent simply blocks it and kills it with, e.g., Divine Verdict or the like, then it's out of play well before your remaining minotaurs deal damage.